# Optimal algorithm for a solution vector that minimizes its own matrix-vector product with a given sparse matrix

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

Given **`A`**, a sparse matrix of binary values with 36 columns and **`n`** rows (where each row is random with the only constraint of each having *at least* 1 one and *at most* 12 ones), is it possible to find an optimal strategy to create **`x`**, a column vector of binary values (with *exactly* 12 ones and 24 zeros), such that each row of the `n by 1` column vector **`b = Ax`** contains a real number (a number between 0 and 12, inclusive), the maximum of which is as small as possible?

I am having trouble with this subset of an optimization problem and I have been attempting to brute-force it to no avail (by generating and testing pseudo-random numbers for **`x`**). Is the task actually NP-hard, or am I just not thinking out of the box enough?

Comment: You say "such that each row... as small as possible", but you can't optimize n outputs at once.  You need to define a single quantity that you want to minimize or maximize.  The most common thing to minimize in situations like this is the sum of the squared values or, equivalently, the magnitude of the resulting column vector, but I don't know if that will work for whatever you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I'm working with the infinity norm i.e. I want to minimize the maximum number out of those n outputs in b. I will update the question to state this.

Comment: Edit: On second thoughts, I think the L2-norm (or sum of squared values, as you stated), might also work. Any ideas in that case?

Comment: Infinity norm will be easier, I think.  It becomes an instance of multidimensional knapsack in that case -- np hard in general, but with only 36 items to choose from, maybe reasonable.  Note that if you're generating Shannon codes, then that's usually done in a systematic way that guarantees the minimum Hamming distance between code words, instead of starting with a given set and finding new ones.

Comment: No, I am not generating Shannon codes. This is one part of a kind of scheduling system. I will look into the multidimensional knapsack problem - I am not too familiar with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's an O(binomial(36, 12) n) = O(n) time algorithm for the problem as stated, but generalizing 36 to m, there's a polynomial-time reduction from independent set to this problem that shows NP-hardness. (Idea: given a graph, emit its adjacency matrix but with ones on the diagonal. The maximum number of vector entries we can set to 1 without causing the infinity norm to exceed 1 equals the size of the maximum independent set. The graph can be assumed [cubic](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1100.html) so that handles a more stringent version of your L1 norm constraint on the rows.)

36 choose 12 is less than 1.3 billion, which doesn't seem like *that* many, but you could also try to solve this problem via an integer programming formulation, since integer program solvers often excel at these kinds of packing problems. (If you need a rec, I use OR-Tools at work and am pretty happy with it.)

Comment: Thank you! I am only interested in this problem for a maximum of 36 items on each row in **A** i.e. 36 rows in **x**. I am not very familiar with integer programming but on a bit of reading it sounds like if A is unimodular (which I think it is since all its entries are 1s and 0s) then I can use the simplex method - is this correct? I am wondering, lest I start barking up a wrong tree. Yes please any help at all that you can provide will be highly welcome, including a general algorithm/idea, or pseudocode, or references. Thank you!

Comment: P.S. I am also wondering if it remains possible to apply your suggested integre programming ideas if we are taking **A** row by row. In the scheduling system of which this is a part, the row values in **A** are sequentially available, so if the algorithm can take advantage of this without waiting until all rows of **A** are available, that would be even more computationally efficient.

Comment: @Cogicero no, you need total unimodularity for that, and in general your rows won't have all determinants of submatrices ±1 unless there's some special substructure that you haven't told me about. Access row by row might be helpful; I think the obvious way would be to keep a candidate solution as the next row comes in, which can be used to prune the search tree. That involves making more sophisticated use of the integer program solver, but the ones suitable for production use typically have the knob required.

Comment: Thank you, David, no there is no special structure at all - except that each row contains only zeros and ones, and that the number of ones on each row is between 1 and 12 inclusive. It was my lack of sufficient knowledge about unimodularity that caused that misguided idea (I just read up some wikipedia articles on integer programming).  Yes, keeping a candidate solution and brute-forcing my way through was what I initially considered but I am not sure it's an effective way for large n. Another user mentioned possibly using a multidimensional knapsack, what do you think about that?

Comment: @Cogicero it's an academic distinction unless you can find a specialized solver, since integer programming would be the first tool that people reach for to solve multi-d knapsack in practice.

Comment: @Cogicero there are exceptions, but generally real world problems have side constraints that academic models don't, and these constraints tend to wreck the nice structure that specialized solvers exploit, so a lot more engineering effort goes into the most general tools.

Comment: Thank you David. There are no other constraints at all in this case, besides all the ones I have mentioned! There are no specialized solvers either, to my knowledge. I'm afraid I may not have sufficient mathematical background to tackle this, but I want to try. If it matters at all, this will be a library within existing PHP code.

Comment: @Cogicero you don't need to implement integer program solving yourself! Here's a guide for calling lpsolve from PHP: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/PHP.htm